# Code not working in Safari but perfectly working in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, safari, anchor

I have an issue with Safari 8:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://10.4.3.40:3000/sample_product_list';
a.download = 'sample_product_list';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

The above code works perfectly with Chrome and Firefox. When I click a button the above code runs a a file gets downloaded. But in Safari, when I click the button nothing happens. No error is printed in the console of Safari. Just nothing happens. When I put a break-point, its hit and I stepped through all the statements, still nothing happens. Whats wrong with my code in Safari?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no error in Console ? Any js error not related to this??

Comment: @AnoopLL Absolutely sure no error popped up. It owrks fine on chrome and firefox

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?
I have same kind of question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797135/angularjss-array-of-objects-is-not-working-in-safari-but-working-in-other-brows

Comment: @user2650000 no...abandoned it.

Answer (score 0):

Add **`/`** at the end of url. it will work:

`a.href = 'http://10.4.3.40:3000/sample_product_list/';`