# Angularjs's array of objects is not working in Safari but working in other browsers

Tags: arrays, angularjs, safari

I am pushing the `http.get()` methods result in a new array. On backend I have django. 
I tried to display the content of array in UI using ng-repeat. Its working absolutely fine with Firebox, Chrome. 
In safari it's displaying nothing. Even if I console the array in controller, it's displaying an empty array. 
There is no error in console.log safari. 
The `console.log(data)` for data from `http.get()` request,is showing empty in safari but in chrome and firebox its showing the expected results.

So is it problem of my code or this issue is related to Safari??

Comment: Well, that shouldn't happen. Have you checked console log in safari ? Hard to help with such a little info

Comment: I checked console log of safari but there is no error related to js or anything, It shows array of object is empty. :(

Comment: Try cleaning the cache of the browser once. It sometimes do the trick. The `$http` call gets stored in cache. You can put you code here so that I can try from my end once.

Comment: Hey i got it. ut was angulajs's issue. not with safari. I just needed to include the "/" after the url. Thank you

Comment: Great. Put this as an answer so that in future it would be easy & helpful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use API call, like `http.get('api/users/')` use `/` to end of  every `http-url`.